# Can't write .dcf file to register an R package in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, package

I have created a package in R and wish to register functions from this as RStudio addins.

The [RStudion help page](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/) instructs us to "Create a file at inst/rstudio/addins.dcf".

However, I do not know how to create a .dcf file and there appears to be very little information online.

Any help most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A DCF (Debian Control File) is a simple file format containing multiple entries of the form:

```
<Key>: <Value>
```

See e.g. the [addins.dcf](https://github.com/rstudio/addinexamples/blob/master/inst/rstudio/addins.dcf) file in the `addinexamples` package for motivation, and `?read.dcf` in an R session for further documentation from R.